# AQGridView: Making a Selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ibooks, aqgridview

I am using [AQGridView](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) to build an iPad app that incorporates a flexible grid like that found in the Apple iBooks app or the Marvel and DC Comics apps. My question is has anyone used AQGridView and can help me with sheding some light on how to make a grid cell selection. It supposedly just makes a sub-class of UITableView but I can't seem to find the correct method for cell selection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

L.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make sure header file (whatever.h) implements: < AQGridViewDelegate >. Then in your implementation file (whatever.m), add the following:

```
- (void) gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    NSLog (@"Selected theArgument=%d\n", index);

}
```

Comment: Yeah... I eventually figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: For anyone else, to actually make a selection (not be notified of selection), which was the first part of the question, you can do this: [[self gridView] selectItemAtIndex:index animated:NO scrollPosition:AQGridViewScrollPositionNone];